# How to change some defaults text showed in the terminal

Tags: terminal, linux-mint

I want to change the text which is shown in the linux terminal
for example i want Show "Hi!Dear" And then run the date command to show the date at the top of the command line.
where can i change these defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit on the cryptic side ...  Is [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) what you are looking for (customising the bash prompt ?)

If it's not feel free to say more about which shell you use and what you really want to achieve.